# Custom Sorting Numerical Objects With Zero Not being first

Tags: vb.net, sorting

If I was to have a list of objects with the following properties:

```
SomeClass.ID
SomeClass.Name
```

The `.ID` can be an integer while `.Name` can be a string, is there a way to sort the objects so that any `0` `.ID` is sorted and placed AFTER the non-zero ID numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `System.Linq`:

```
Dim sorted = From o In yourObjectList
             Order By o.Id = 0, o.Id
yourObjectList = sorted.ToList()
```

That's a conditional order, because `o.Id = 0` will evaluate to either `True` or `False`. You want the non-zero first, so order `Ascending`(default) since `True` is "greater than" `False`.

This is the same in the (in VB.NET ugly) method syntax:

```
yourObjectList = yourObjectList.
        OrderBy(Function(o) o.Id = 0).
        ThenBy(Function(o) o.Id).
        ToList()
```

You can also rewrite it to use the conditional operator, if that's clearer for you:

```
yourObjectList = yourObjectList.
        OrderBy(Function(o) If(o.Id = 0, 1, 0)).
        ThenBy(Function(o) o.Id).
        ToList()
```

The `If`-operator it treats Id's with zero as `1` and all others as `0`, so the `<> 0` will come first.

Comment: Will this still keep the 0 away from the ascending sorted IDs?

Comment: Yes, because as the first order-condition it will make 2 branches, those that have Id=0, which is most likely only one item, and all others. So you will first see all others, ordered by Id Asc and then the zero(s).

Comment: This will work if you don't mind creating a new list. To sort an existing list in place, the comparison logic would be the same but the usage details would be slightly different.

Comment: Thank you both I got the desired result.